# Angular return ZoneAwarePromise instead of String

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, rxjs

i am expecting a string return for the giver code but it is returning ZoneAwarePromise

**in service**

```
  getCoveredPeriod() {
    let loanDetails = this.getLoanDetails().toPromise();
    loanDetails.then((res: any) => {
      const coveredPeriodStart = new Date(
        res.coveredperiodstartdate
      ).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'long',
        day: 'numeric',
      });
      const coveredPeriodEnd = new Date(
        res.coveredperiodenddate
      ).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'long',
        day: 'numeric',
      });
      this.coveredPeriod = `${coveredPeriodStart} to ${coveredPeriodEnd}`;
      return this.coveredPeriod;
    });
  }
```

**in component**

```
  coveredPeriod: any;

  this.coveredPeriod = this.basicFormsService.getCoveredPeriod()
```

i am expencting this.coveredPeriod = string but am getting

```
ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: true, __zone_symbol__value: undefined}
__zone_symbol__state: true
__zone_symbol__value: undefined
Symbol(Symbol.species): (...)
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): (...)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: not working .. getting 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.ts(80007)

Comment: You are missing a `return` in your `getCoveredPeriod()` method.  Also, you need to use `await`.  See @Shashank's answer.

Comment: @shashank-vivek not working. getting undefined

Answer (score 2):

Can you try

```
  getCoveredPeriod() {
    let loanDetails = this.getLoanDetails().toPromise();
    return loanDetails.then((res: any) => {
      const coveredPeriodStart = new Date(
        res.coveredperiodstartdate
      ).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'long',
        day: 'numeric',
      });
      const coveredPeriodEnd = new Date(
        res.coveredperiodenddate
      ).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'long',
        day: 'numeric',
      });
      this.coveredPeriod = `${coveredPeriodStart} to ${coveredPeriodEnd}`;
      return this.coveredPeriod;
    });
  }
```

and then

```
this.coveredPeriod = await this.basicFormsService.getCoveredPeriod()
```

Comment: @Sreenath: Thanks for letting me know. Can you please create a demo code on stackblitz.com ? In that way, I can try to fix it quickly